# $velocitycount not working

Tags: jira, velocity

I don't understand how to use $velocitycount. I've followed lots of answers, but nothing seems to be working for me.

I have a For loop:

```
    #set($CountofIssues = 1)
    #foreach($issue in $issues)
        $CountofIssues= $velocitycount
        #<fo:block>$CountofIssues</fo:block>
    #end
```

I've also tried `$CountofIssues: $velocitycount`, but obviously I'm missing something fundamental.

In the output, I just get a load of 1's.

FYI, I'm using Velocity through the PDF View extension to JIRA.

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue. Are you trying to set $CountofIssues to the Velocity loop counter?

Comment: i think you're supposed to set the value CountofIssues, so `#set ($CountofIssues = $velocitycount)`

Answer (score 1):

The [foreach documentation for Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#loops) explains how to use the $velocityCount variable which is just a loop counter set at the beginning of the `foreach` loop.

Assume I have set a list of strings in my context to pass to the Velocity template. The following code:

```
#foreach($item in $myList)
    <p>$velocityCount&nbsp$item</p>
#end
```

Would produce the following HTML:

```
<p>1 stuff1</p>
<p>2 stuff2</p>
<p>3 stuff3</p>
<p>4 stuff4</p>
<p>5 stuff5</p>
<p>6 stuff6</p>
```

If you want to set a variable to equal the `$velocityCount` in your foreach loop, then you need to use the `#set` directive to set your variable:

```
#foreach($item in $myList)
    #set($myVar = $velocityCount)
    <p>$myVar</p>
#end
```

However, in your case, I don't believe setting another variable is really necessary as you can just use the `$velocityCount` variable directly.

Note: I have tested this in JIRA 6.3.12 by creating a plugin with a servlet that renders a Velocity template. I have not tested this using the PDF View extension, but I doubt there would be any issues.

Note 2: `$velocityCount` starts it's index at 1 but this can be changed in the `velocity.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I've no idea how this is supposed to work, but for what I need I found I could just use `#if($issues.size() > 1)`